# Pull non blank from previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have data as below (first 3 columns). I would like to create the 4th column - `newstatus`.

Logic for the `newstatus` column is that

1. for each pk2
2. if column `status` is blank then pull value from the
   most recent row where `status` is either new or old.

Because of that row 3 gets value new which is from row 2 while row 9 gets value old from row 7. row 8 is ignored because it has value `ignore`

```
pk  status  pk2        newstatus
1           1   
2   new     1   
3           1          new
4   ignore  1   
5   ignore  1   
6           2   
7   old     2   
8   ignore  2   
9           2          old
10  new     2
```

Comment: Why no newstatus for row 6?

Comment: because it is the first row of `pk2`=2. There are no previous rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use this script

```
WITH OuterT AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pk2 ORDER BY pk1) num FROM tbl
)
SELECT pk1,[Status],pk2,
(CASE WHEN num=1 or [Status] !='' THEN ''
WHEN num !=1 THEN
(SELECT TOP 1 innerT.[Status] FROM OuterT innerT WHERE innerT.pk2 =OuterT.pk2 and ([status] ='new' or [status] ='old') and num != 1 and innerT.pk1 < OuterT.pk1  ORDER BY pk1 DESC)
END) newstatus
FROM OuterT
```

How it works:

I used `common_table_expression` that its name is `OuterT`

```
WITH OuterT AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pk2 ORDER BY pk1) num FROM tbl
)
```

And I used `ROW_NUMBER` that its name is `num`

Inner result of `OuterT` is :

[image: inner result of outerT]

And then I used a `CASE` that Include your logic base on `OuterT`

```
(CASE WHEN num=1 or [Status] !='' THEN ''
WHEN num !=1 THEN
(SELECT TOP 1 innerT.[Status] FROM OuterT innerT WHERE innerT.pk2 =OuterT.pk2 and ([status] ='new' or [status] ='old') and num != 1 and innerT.pk1 < OuterT.pk1  ORDER BY pk1 DESC)
END) newstatus
```

And final result is :

[image]

Note: if you want to use script just replace “tbl” with your table name

Comment: could you explain the logic? also why is OuterT required? cannot we use Pk1?

Comment: I explained the logic

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm . . . This might be simplest using `outer apply`

```
select t.*,
       (case when status is null then t2.status end) as new_status
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.pk2 = t.pk2 and t2.status in ('old', 'new') and
            t2.pk1 < t.pk1
      order by t2.pk1 desc
     ) t2;
```

There is actually a way of doing this without subqueries . . . and this might be the most efficient method:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status is null and
                  max(case when status = 'old' then pk1 end) over (partition by pk2 order by pk1) >
                  max(case when status = 'new' then pk2 else 0 end order by pk1) over (partition by pk2)
             then 'old'
             when status is null and
                  max(case when status = 'new' then pk1 end) over (partition by pk2 order by pk1) >
                  max(case when status = 'old' then pk2 else 0 end) over (partition by pk2 order by pk1)
             then 'new'
      end) as new_status
from t;
```

Comment: ` max(case when status = 'old' then pk1 end) over (partition by pk2) >
                  max(case when status = 'new' then pk2 else 0 end) over (partition by pk2)`     
                     why do you have pk2 in the second max? shouldn't it be pk1?

Comment: also how would your code ensure that we are looking at only the previous rows and not all the rows?

Comment: @user2543622 . . . In the first query, the condition `t2.pk1 < t.pk1` does that.  The second query left out the `order by clauses in window frames.  Good catch.  It now has the right logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.

The idea is to build groups of rows with a cumulative count that increases every time a "new" or "old" status is met. You can then use `first_value()` to access the corresponding status whenever needed.

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when status is null and grp > 0
        then first_value(status) over(partition by pk2, grp order by pk1)
        else status
    end as new_status
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when status in ('old', 'new') then 1 else 0 end)
            over(partition by pk2 order by pk1) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: could you explain the logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is old school, no windowing function and no OUTER APPLY.

```
;with max_prior_pk_cte as (
    select tt.pk, tt.pk2,
           max(ttt.pk) max_pk
    from
      #testTable tt
     join
      #testTable ttt on tt.pk2=ttt.pk2
                        and tt.pk>ttt.pk
    where tt.[status] is null
          and ttt.[status] in ('old', 'new')
    group by tt.pk, tt.pk2)
select
  t.*, t_prior.[status] new_status
from
  #testTable t
 left join
  max_prior_pk_cte mppc on t.pk=mppc.pk
 left join
  #testTable t_prior on mppc.max_pk=t_prior.pk;
```

Here's some sample data:

```
drop table if exists #testTable;
go
create table #testTable(
  pk        int unique not null,
  [status]  varchar(20),
  pk2       int not null);

insert into #testTable(pk, [status], pk2) values
(1, null, 1),
(2, 'new', 1),   
(3, null, 1),
(4, 'ignore', 1),
(5, 'ignore', 1),
(6, null, 2),   
(7, 'old', 2),   
(8, 'ignore', 2),   
(9, null, 2),
(10, 'new', 2);
```